# Csharp: Find & Replace string match between specific characters || in a string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching

I have a string like:

```
string originalStringBefore = "http://www.abc.com?a=||ThisIsForRndNumber||&qq=hello&jj=||ThisIsForRndNumberAlso||";
```

I want every string which comes between || to be replaced with a random number.

Now, the random number generation is easy, but i can't find the way to write a Regular expression to search the string using a pattern and replace it.

I don't want to do it by string manipulation functions.

Expected Solution/ outcome:

```
string originalStringAfter = "http://www.abc.com?a=||254877787||&qq=hello&jj=||6594741454||";
```

Comment: Why exactly isn't `&qq=hello&jj=` supposed to be matched by the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string originalStringBefore = "http://www.abc.com?a=||ThisIsForRndNumber||&qq=hello&jj=||ThisIsForRndNumberAlso||";

Random r = new Random();
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\|\|.*?\|\|");
Console.WriteLine(rgx.Replace(originalStringBefore, "||" + r.Next(int.MaxValue) + "||"));
```

Comment: This happens to work on the OP's string, but what if two to-be-replaced strings follow in a row, like `||ReplaceThis||ReplaceThatToo||`?

Comment: This is a different logic. If this is what he wanted then the result on his oridinal string would have been: `"http://www.abc.com?a=||12345||123456||124567||"`. No?

Comment: @Tim: Good one! But this is not the problem here :) But Thanks to point out for others and me. :)

Comment: @Petar, @Mazhar: Specs are hazy, crystal ball is broken. :)

Comment: @Petar: Your solution worked! I marked it answered, thanks man! 
@Tim, thanks goes to you also. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want this regex:

```
(?<=\|\|)\w+(?=\|\|)
```

which finds alphanumeric between `||` and leaves strings that contain non-alphanumeric characters (like `&`) alone.

Then, in C#:

```
public String ComputeReplacement(Match m) {
    return RandomNumberString();
}

resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?<=\|\|)\w+(?=\|\|)", new MatchEvaluator(ComputeReplacement));
```

Comment: But there can be any character between these ||, except | itself. 
\w should be removed in that case?

Comment: @Mazhar: Then why aren't you replacing `&qq=hello&jj=`?

Comment: I can't simply, only the value of querystring parameter. otherwise it's a overhead. when we know what to replace, which is only between ||

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that. `&qq=hello&jj=` *is* between `||`. What *exactly*  are the rules that determine which parts should or should not be replaced?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the regular expression replace command pasted below

```
string result = Regex.Replace(originalStringBefore, @"\|\|.*?\|\|","||ReplaceCharactors||");
```

how ever to write reguler expression's go through [this](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx) site hope this wil help you

Thanks.